# can we deploy an react js application without source(src folder) code locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs

some background:this is my first react application and my assumption is build in react is similar to binary files in c++

question : this is for a react application which sole purpose is to run locally. is there anyway we can do npm start only with build

have tried to delete the src folder after building.

expected result is the app should run as usual.
actual result : app crashes saying, index.js file is missing

Comment: You need how you config your application

Comment: So your question is how deployment strategies are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm start won`t work with build version,
you need to install serve and run build using serve locally on your machine

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

ref: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment